# Failing to login to website using python's requests library

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

**edit** I believe the issue is that when opening the website for the first time, you must click a "Our privacy policy has been updated..." Accept button. I'm now looking into how I might go about "clicking" this button using python requests, however the button calls a javascript function so I'm not sure if it's possible to do with just the requests library.

I am attempting to write a script for this website: https://rocket-league.com/

I need to be logged in to perform my tasks, but I'm having trouble logging in.

I feel as though I've accounted for all the correct params. I fetch the csrf_token dynamically using regex. Maybe I need to do something with the cookies, but I'm not sure what?

This is my first attempt at writing a script that interacts with websites so I'm sorry if I'm naive.

I'd be grateful for any insights that aren't just a disguised way of telling me I'm dumb and/or lazy.

Here is my code so far:

```
import requests;
import re;

payload = {
    'csrf_token': '',
    'email': 'myemail',
    'password': 'mypassword',
    'submit': 'Login'
}

url = 'https://rocket-league.com/login'

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(url)

    m = re.search("<input type='hidden' name='csrf_token' value='(.+)'", r.text)
    if m: payload['csrf_token'] = m.group(1)
    else: print("couldnt find csrf_token")

    p = s.post('https://rocket-league.com/functions/login.php', data=payload)
    print(p.text)
```

Running this code prints out HTML that still has the login form in it which means I am not being logged in.

When I login from my browser with the developer tools > network open, I get this information for my post request:

Headers:

```
Request URL: https://rocket-league.com/functions/login.php
Request method: POST
Status code: 302 Found
Version HTTP/2.0
```

Cookies:

```
__cfduid: d2c83b2c9ad728195366656a56592f6d71549577451
acceptedPrivacyPolicy: 2.0
euconsent: BObnsHAObnsHAABABAENCF-AAAAkF7_______9______9uz_Ov_v_f__33e8__9v_l_7_-___u_-33d4-_1vf99yfm1-7ftr3tp_87ues2_Xur__59__3z3_tphPhA
fantasy_rlcs_id: hA8fga9ghIgaFGA9
PHPSESSID: lrse3tgov95eg574sqga6la9jc
```

Params:

```
csrf_token: 3f2588113e8921f52dc3eb78e51246a1
email: myemail
password: mypassword
submit: Login
```

Here is the actual HTML for the login form:

```
<form class="rlg-form" method="post" action="/functions/login.php">
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="3accad82ad0957cab634f805a7e28beb">
<input class="rlg-input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
<input class="rlg-input" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required="">
<fieldset class="rlg-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="rememberme-login">
<label for="rememberme-login">Remember me?</label>
</fieldset>
<input class="rlg-btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```